# How can I create multi-styled text in VCL?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I need text with different colors (red and green) on a single line.

I've looked at TRichEdit, but it doesn't seem to allow changing text properties within a line. Which component would allow that ?

Comment: TRichEdit DOES allow changing text properties char by char.

Comment: You have to *select* the desired char(s) first (`SelStart` and `SelLength` properties) and then use the `SelAttributes` property to format the selected text with desired characteristics, like color. Rinse and repeat as needed.

Comment: From a project of mine with AdvRichEditor  t: TTextElement;       t := AdvrichEditor.AddText('Description', taCenter);
      t.Color := clYellow;
      t.FontSize := 12;
      t.FontStyle := [fsBold, fsUnderline];